# Run multiple cmd files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

What I want to do is start a .bat file that start other .cmd files. I have accomplished this with this command

```
start /D "path_to_folder" file1.cmd
start /D "path_to_folder" file2.cmd
start /D "path_to_folder" file3.cmd
```

The problem Im having is that I want the first bat that starts the other files, to close when all of the other cmd's have finished.

If I add the /WAIT command to every line, they will start one after another and not in parallel.

I've tried putting the /WAIT command on the last line, but sometimes that command finishes earlier than the others and the main bat file closes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the accepted answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting):

```
(
start /D "path_to_folder" file1.cmd
start /D "path_to_folder" file2.cmd
start /D "path_to_folder" file3.cmd
) | set /P "="
```

This method does not modify the standard output of the started .cmd files.

Comment: Interesting.  Don't remember seeing you post that one before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works fine, but I use a program Backburner(network rendering) to start the bat file and when the bat file is about to exit or exit (I cant really know) I get an error in the Backburner. I know that this is the error of the program and not the bat file itself. So my question is can I use something different than:  set /P "=" , cause I think that maybe is causing the problem Im having.

Answer (score 1):

We have had a few discussion about this over on dostips.com.

Here are some of the ideas they had come up with.

```
A.bat | B.bat | C.bat | D.bat | E.bat
```

Another otpion

```
rem you may also use the following if you wnat to see status messages of all processes.
rem A.bat>con | B.bat>con | C.bat>con | D.bat>con | E.bat
```

And one more

```
start "" /wait cmd /c temp.bat |start "" /wait cmd /c temp2.bat
```

Comment: Or, you may want to use instead of `>con` to log your results: `>yourlogfile.txt` and remember the use of one `>` will overwrite your log and the use of two `>>` will apend.