# What is the use of ".lock" in batch file while implementing multithreading?

Tags: windows, multithreading, batch-file, cmd

Here is the code. As I am new to batch script I cannot understand why **.lock** is used and why it is less than equal to **9**.

```
set "lock=%temp%\wait%random%.lock"

start "" cmd /c 9>="%lock%1" abcd.bat 4441 %tempdate%

start "" cmd /c 9>="%lock%2" pqrs.bat 4442 %tempdate%

for %%N in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do (

        9>="%lock%%%N" || goto :Wait

) 2>nul
```

Comment: *.lock* is a file extension, and it is never compared against 9. The comparisons are done with against the environment variable *%lock%*.

Comment: There isn't any comparision at all. `9>=` is syntactical equal to `9>` and this is a file redirection operation.

Comment: If the purpose of this code is wait until all started processes ends, then a much simpler solution is given at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting/33586872#33586872)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`9>` isn't a compare expression, it's a redirection of the output stream 9.
The syntax `9>=` is nonsense, as the `=` has no meaning here as it will be dropped.

Output stream 9 normally doesn't exist, the output will be empty files "wait1000.lock1" and "wait1000.lock2" (assuming `%random%` is 1000 in this case).

The FOR loop simply tests if it can write to the same file, this will be blocked until the batch files exits and the write lock will be released.
And while at least one file is locked the command `9>"%lock%%%N"` fails and then the `goto :wait` will be executed.

Btw. The label `:Wait` is missing in your sample file,
 it should be inserted just before the FOR-loop

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful.