# Batch file to open program, move files and then replace the files on manual program close

Tags: windows, batch-file

To be more specific, I would like to use a batch file to load "Program X". Then once the program is fully loaded and open on the screen, move a few files from "Folder A" to "Folder B". Then when Program X is manually exited, move the previously moved files back to Folder B. Here is what I tried, but didn't work. I didn't think it would.

```
start "" "C:\ProgramX.exe"
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File1.txt" "C:\FolderB\"
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File2.txt" "C:\FolderB\"

/wait "C:\ProgramX.exe"

move /-y "C:\FolderB\File1.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
move /-y "C:\FolderB\File2.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
```

Originally I made two separate batch files that simply move the files back and forth (I manually open and close the program) and it works, but I would like to have just one batch file that loads the program, then moves the files and then moves them back once I have exited the program.

Comment: Please not only say, that it does not work. Descripe what the code does and what not next time

Comment: It successfully started the program, but moved the files before the program fully loaded...and then it promptly moved the files right back to the original folder and exited. I only know this because I inserted pauses between each command so I could see what was going on.

Comment: There's no way to wait for a program to have fully initialized and display its main UI in a generic way, regardless of programming language or platform. The solution is necessarily going to be application-specific. Likewise, there is no way to discern between manual and automated application shutdown.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't agree. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42576985/778560).

Comment: @Aacini: You can agree or disagree with opinions. I stated established facts. If you feel like disagreeing with facts, you need a very strong tool. As it stands, your proposed solution does not address the issue I outlined in my previous comment. There is no way to generically, at the system level know, when any given application's initialization has run to a particular point, where it is ready to respond to a specific change in global state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the most efficient way:

```
@echo off

rem Start the program and wait until it ends before continue
(
start "process running" "arj.exe"
ping -n 2 localhost > NUL
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File1.txt" "C:\FolderB\" > NUL
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File2.txt" "C:\FolderB\" > NUL
) | set /P "="

move /-y "C:\FolderB\File1.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
move /-y "C:\FolderB\File2.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
```

In this method the waiting state is *event driven* (controlled by the OS), so it does not waste CPU time! Further details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting/33586872#33586872).

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please, provide a clear description of what the problem is. Each individual command should run as intended and the wait method was proven already in the linked answer...

Comment: I inserted my program and files into this example and the program did not launch and the files did not move. I only changed "arj.exe" with my program location, as well as the folder and file locations. The rest I left as your example. Did I miss something?

Comment: Please, remove the lines with parentheses and be sure that the code run in the same way as your original code, with no wait. After that, reinsert the lines with parentheses...

Comment: Removing the parentheses made the program load and the files moved like the original with no wait, but adding the parentheses seems to kill the whole thing. Nothing happened.

Comment: Ops! Remove the `rem` command! I already did it in the posted code. This is a subtle bug that appears now and then... **`:(`**

Comment: what's the `| set /P "="` for?

Comment: May I ask you to select (check-mark) this answer and upvote it?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Is the way to wait for the started process. The `set /P` command would terminate when anyone of the commands in the `( block )` outputs a line, but `start` command don't show any line _in this cmd.exe_. This way, `set /P` keeps waiting for input until the process started by `start` ends. At that point the pipe line associated to the `( block )` is released, the `set /P` Stdin is closed and `set /P` command is terminated by the OS.

Comment: if it waits for the started process then why do we need the ping to delay?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Because _"the only problem is the files move to the new folder before the program loads. I guess I could just add a 'pause' to wait for it to load"_, as the OP explained in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a loop (goto) which looks if the programm is still running (if ..then) and you put the move back of the files after the loop.

Checkout this snippet:

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq notepad.exe" /FO CSV > search.log

FOR /F %%A IN (search.log) DO IF %%~zA EQU 0 GOTO end

start notepad.exe

:end

del search.log
```

It checks if notepad.exe is running. If it is not running, it will start notepad.exe.

Comment: What is the problem now? To wait some seconds, you can implement the code "ping -n 2 localhost > NUL". The "2" says, how long it has to wait. So choose a time, which is longer then the time needed for full load of the application

Comment: @xs6 to sleep [better use `timeout 1 >nul`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/995714)

Answer (score -1):

The easy way would be

```
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File1.txt" "C:\FolderB\"
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File2.txt" "C:\FolderB\"
"C:\ProgramX.exe"

move /-y "C:\FolderB\File1.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
move /-y "C:\FolderB\File2.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
```

or

```
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File1.txt" "C:\FolderB\"
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File2.txt" "C:\FolderB\"
start /wait "" "C:\ProgramX.exe"

move /-y "C:\FolderB\File1.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
move /-y "C:\FolderB\File2.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
```

but if you insist on doing the `move` after the `start`,

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
start /b "process running" "arj.exe"
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File1.txt" "C:\FolderB\"
move /-y "C:\FolderA\File2.txt" "C:\FolderB\"

ECHO waiting
:wait
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq arj.exe"|FINDSTR /i "arj.exe">nul&IF NOT errorlevel 1 timeout /t 1 >nul&goto wait

move /-y "C:\FolderB\File1.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
move /-y "C:\FolderB\File2.txt" "C:\FolderA\"
ECHO finished

pause

GOTO :EOF
```

I used `arj.exe` here to test the methodology. Naturally, it could be any executable that exits under user-control, unlike `notepad` that exits immediately having instantiated an interactive instance.

I'm presuming that there will be only one instance of `programx` active on the system at any one time.

The `echo`s and `pause` are present simply to demonstrate the batch program state.

Comment: So close @Magoo! The only problem is the files move to the new folder before the program loads. I guess I could just add a 'pause' to wait for it to load...unless there is a better way? Thanks

Comment: You could add a `timeout` so that the user doesn't have to do anything.

Comment: That works!! Thank you @Magoo! My only question would be if this program was left open all day, would the batch file cause the computer to bog down since it is continuously looking to see if the program closes?

Comment: Bog down? No. It's looking for the task once per second - should be minimal impact. By increasing the `timeout` parameter, it will lessen the impact if required, the downside being that the "move back" average time afer mainapp closure will be increased.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Very helpful!