# Execute multiple batch files concurrently and monitor if their process is completed

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parallel-processing

I have a main batch file which calls multiple batch files. I want to be able to execute all these batch files at the same time. Once they are all done, I have further processes that needs to carry on in the main batch file.

When I use 'Start' to call the multiple batch files, I'm able to kick off all batch files concurrently but I lose tracking of them. (Main batch file thinks their processes are done the moment it executes other batch files).

When I use 'Call', I'm able to monitor the batch file process, but it kicks off the batch files sequentially instead of concurrently.

Is there a way around this? I have limited permissions on this PC and I'm trying to accomplish this using Batch only.

Main Batch file

```
call first.bat
call second.bat
call third.bat
:: echo only after all batch process done
echo done!
```

first.bat

```
timeout /t 10
```

second.bat

```
timeout /t 10
```

third.bat

```
timeout /t 10
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the simplest and most efficient way to solve this problem:

```
(
start first.bat
start second.bat
start third.bat
) | pause

echo done!
```

In this method the waiting state in the main file is *event driven*, so it does not consume any CPU time. The `pause` command would terminate when anyone of the commands in the `( block )` outputs a character, but `start` commands don't show any output *in this cmd.exe*. In this way, `pause` keeps waiting for a char until all processes started by `start` commands ends. At that point the pipe line associated to the `( block )` is closed, so the `pause` Stdin is closed and the command is terminated by `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Nice, I forgot about this (again!). Note that this approach has the same problem my code has: anything started from the batch files that inherit handles and that remains running after the batch file has ended will keep the pipe open and the main batch file paused.

Comment: Not sure how I never saw this technique until now - but I like it!

Comment: Would this work with the start /B switch too? Could you shed some light on the theory here?

Comment: @BikerDude: See Eryk Sun's _comments_ below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting/33586872#33586872)

Answer (score 3):

This will generate a temporary file and lock it by creating a redirection to it, starting the batch subprocesses inside this redirection. When all the subprocesses end the redirection is closed and the temporary file is deleted.

While the subprocesses are running, the file is locked, and we can test this  trying to rename the file. If we can rename the file, subprocesses have ended, else some of the processes are still running.

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%t in ("%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do (

        echo Starting subprocesses
        9> "%%~ft" (
            start "" cmd /c subprocess.bat
            start "" cmd /c subprocess.bat
            start "" cmd /c subprocess.bat
            start "" cmd /c subprocess.bat
            start "" cmd /c subprocess.bat
        )

        echo Waiting for subprocesses to end
        break | >nul 2>nul (
            for /l %%a in (0) do @(ren "%%~ft" "%%~nxt" && exit || ping -n 2 "")
        )
        echo Done    

    ) & del "%%~ft"
```

**note**: any process started inside the subprocesses will also hold the redirection and the lock. If your code leaves something running, this can not be used.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
:: set batchnames to run
SET "batches=first second third"
:: make a tempdir
:maketemp
SET /a tempnum=%random%
SET "tempdir=%temp%\%tempnum%"
IF EXIST "%tempdir%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (MD "%tempdir%")

FOR %%a IN (%batches%) DO START "%%a" %%a "%tempdir%\%%a"

:wait
timeout /t 1 >nul
FOR %%a IN (%batches%) DO IF exist "%tempdir%\%%a" GOTO wait

RD "%tempdir%" /S /Q

GOTO :EOF
```

Where the batches are constructed like

```dos
@ECHO OFF
:: just delay for 5..14 seconds after creating a file "%1", then delete it and exit
SETLOCAL
ECHO.>"%~1"
SET /a timeout=5+(%RANDOM% %% 10)
timeout /t %timeout% >NUL
DEL /F /Q "%~1"
EXIT
```

That is, each called batch first creates a file in the temporary directory, then deletes it after the required process is run. The filename to create/delete is provided as the first parameter to the batch and "quoted" because the `temp` directoryname typically contains separators.

The mainline simply creates a temporary directory and invokes the subprocedures, then repeatedly waits 1 second and checks whether the subprocedures' flagfile have all been deleted. Only if they have all been deleted with the procedure continue to delete the temporary directory

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762349/9689416). I was also looking for similar task. Objective was to run multiple commands parallel and extract output (stdout & error) of all parallel processes. Then wait for all parallel processes to finish and execute another command. Following is a sample code for BAT file, can be executed in CMD:

```
(
start "" /B cmd /c ping localhost -n 6 ^>nul
timeout /t 5 /nobreak
start "" /B /D "C:\users\username\Desktop" cmd /c dir ^> dr.txt ^2^>^&^1
start "" /B cmd /c ping localhost -n 11 ^>nul
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
) | pause
Echo waited
timeout /t 12 /nobreak
```

All the statements inside `()` are executed first, wait for them to complete, then last two lines are executed. All commands begining with `start` are executed simultaneously.