# How start a program via command line after the previous process terminated itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduler

I run a program like `notepad.exe` via command line.

After the process terminated itself after completion of task of the started application, I need to run another program via command line, for example `winword.exe`.

So I would like a behavior like a scheduler, waiting in background up to completion of first process and then initiate start of another process.

Can I achieve this in Windows? And if yes, how?

Comment: What's the other program you need to run? And what happens when that one dies?

Comment: `START /WAIT NOTEPAD & DIR` for example

Comment: `start notepad.exe | pause & winword.exe` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754374/execute-multiple-batch-files-concurrently-and-monitor-if-their-process-is-comple/43762349#43762349) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting/33586872#33586872) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Batch file solutions

For the example `Notepad.exe` and `Winword.exe` the solution is quite simple with following batch file:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe
start Winword.exe
```

Windows command interpreter `cmd.exe` first starts *Windows Notepad* and halts execution of the batch file until `Notepad.exe` terminated itself which means the user

- pressed <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> on keyboard, or
- clicked on **X** symbol on right side of title bar of *Notepad* window, or
- clicked in menu **File** on menu item **Exit**, or
- double clicked on application symbol on left side of title bar of *Notepad* window, or
- clicked once on application symbol on left side of title bar of *Notepad* window and clicked next on last application context menu item **Close**.

Then internal command **START** of `cmd.exe` is used to start *Microsoft Word* in a separate process parallel to running command process. For that reason `cmd.exe` continues the batch file processing immediately after executing **START** while *Microsoft Word* is running parallel and exits because there is no more command line.

The application to start must be specified usually with full path if the directory containing the executable is not included in environment variable **PATH**, enclosed in double quotes if the path contains a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. Please take a look on [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) for details on how Windows command interpreter finds executables and scripts specified on command line or in a batch file without path (and without file extension). So best would be as second line something like:

```
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\Winword.exe"
```

This command line starts 32-bit *Microsoft Word 2010* installed in standard installation directory on a computer running 64-bit Windows. The additional empty argument string `""` is necessary because command **START** would interpret otherwise the full qualified name of application to start enclosed in double quotes as title for a new console window. So the command **START** would start a new command process with the title `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Winword.exe` for the console window without specifying explicitly an empty title with `""` as first argument.

Why is using just `start Winword.exe` working?

The directory containing `Winword.exe` is not included in environment variable **PATH**. But as long as `Winword.exe` is installed at all, this command line nevertheless results in starting *Microsoft Word*. The reason is correct registration of application `Winword.exe` in Windows registry during installation. For that reason the command **START** is capable to find out where `Winword.exe` is installed and execute it. For details on how this works see answer on [Where is “START” searching for executables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27386403/3074564)

The three lines in batch file can be also optimized to a [single line with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564):

```
@%SystemRoot%\Notepad.exe & start Winword.exe
```

But this single command line can't be used directly in a command prompt window because of `cmd.exe` executes in this case *Windows Notepad* and *Microsoft Word* parallel.

---

### Command line solutions

The command line solution for usage directly from within a command prompt window is:

```
start /wait Notepad.exe & start Winword.exe
```

This starts *Windows Notepad* in a separate process using command **START** with explicitly waiting for termination of `Notepad.exe` because of using additionally the **START** parameter `/wait` before one more **START** is executed to start *Microsoft Word*. There is no need of `""` as empty title string here because of no argument string in this command line is enclosed in double quotes.

But this command line solution has one disadvantage: the command prompt window can't be used further as long as *Windows Notepad* is running.

So better would be starting from within current command prompt window a new command process with minimized window which first executes *Windows Notepad*, halts command line execution until *Notepad* terminates itself, then starts *Microsoft Word* and exits immediately after starting `Winword.exe`. This can be done with following command line:

```
start "Notepad & Winword" /min cmd.exe /C "start /wait Notepad.exe & start Winword.exe"
```

This command line results in starting `cmd.exe` as separate process, with a console window being minimized because of option `/min` of command **START**, with a console window title `Notepad & Winword`, which closes itself because of option `/C` of **CMD**, after first starting `Notepad.exe` and waiting for *Notepad* termination before starting `Winword.exe` not waiting for termination.

Well, the additional, minimized console window with title `Notepad & Winword` is in real of no usage for the user. Therefore better would be the command line:

```
start "" /B cmd.exe /C "start /wait Notepad.exe & start Winword.exe"
```

The additional command process is started in this case with no window (in background) because of usage of option `/B` of command **START**. An empty title is specified here as no console window is shown at all.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cmd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `start /?`