# Running batch scripts in background and check status

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I've 2 batch scripts to run in background:
script1.bat
script2.bat
And the third batch script to run only after the 1st two scripts are executed
script3.bat

My main script  main.bat calls these 2 in background:
start /B cmd /C script1.bat
start /B cmd /C script2.bat

These 2 scripts take 1 hour each to complete and hence need to complete in background.

I want the main.bat to check if these 2 scripts completed and only then execute script3.bat.

Is there any way I can do this?

Below are the scripts contents
script1.bat

```
@echo off 
set "MyProcess=script1.exe"
*** do something that takes 1 hour****
```

script2.bat

```
@echo off
set "MyProcess=script2.exe"
*** do something that takes 1 hour****
```

script3.bat

```
@echo off 
set "MyProcess=script3.exe"
*** do something that takes 1 hour****
```

main.bat

```
@echo off 
start /B cmd /C script1.bat
start /B cmd /C script2.bat 
call script3.bat
```

Comment: Is [`START /W`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) perhaps of use?

Comment: I edited my question. I don't think that'll work. Will it?

Comment: Your batch files don't appear to do anything except attempt to set an environment variable. This should not take an hour to do. Either there is something seriously wrong with your computer, or these are not your batch files. Please correct the information, look at the information in link I gave you, and proceed from there.

Comment: There are additonal tasks done in each script

Comment: Do `script1` and `script2` execute in parallel, or sequentially?

Comment: Execute parallely

Comment: I think this might be better done in PowerShell, but you should perhaps take a look at [`tasklist`](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html).

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33584587/2152082) with some different methods to to it (which one you choose, depens on your scripts).

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: 'cause you don't know which script will be faster.