# Run Another batch file in a batch file using python subprocess mode

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I want to run a bat file named Mainfile.bat in location of C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop

**Mainfile.bat contents**

```
start cmd /k call C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\1.bat

start cmd /k call C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\2.bat

start cmd /k call C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\3.bat
```

Once Mainfile.bat started , it should run three bat files specified in the bat file.

To do is , i wrote a code in python like,

```
subprocess.call("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Mainfile.bat",stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)

print "Finished"
```

**Expected Output:**

What want i want is,if i run a Mainfile.bat file ,that should executes the commands.In that, Each bat file in Mainfile.bat take some time to finish the process and it will automatically close once its finished.
After finished running all those bat file(1.bat,2.bat,3.bat) only-- i need to print "finished" in console.

**Actual output:**

But,Once it run Mainfile.bat file , it executes the three bat files and it immediately print "finished" in console..How can i achieve the Expected output?

Got Expected Output :

By changing the content in the Mainfile.bat

```
(
  start 1.bat
  start 2.bat
  start 3.bat
) | pause

echo done!
```

Comment: Try with `shell=True`? Maybe if you specify execution through the shell, it will block till the shell closes.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ No, i have tried it , its not working

Comment: You do not need to use **CALL** with the **START** command. That will not fix your problem. Just letting you know that code is not necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait all batch files to finish before exiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    my_process = subprocess.Popen(os.path.abspath('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Mainfile.bat'), shell=True)
    stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate()
    my_process.wait()
```

You can use communicate() which will wait until process completes execution.

Comment: that's also not working, its prints finished immediately.

Comment: @pavithranG can you try wait()

Comment: All the batch files release control back to the main batch file. So you either monitor for the finished execution of the three batch files or code the batch file so that it does not release control back to the main batch file until all three batch files are done.

Comment: @Squashman, i tried like you said for "monitor for the finished execution of the three batch files" ..it worked perfectly