# Batch delay Excuting python in sequence

Tags: python, batch-file, gis

I use batch files to perform repetitive/tedious GIS tasks outside of a GIS environment. I am looking for ways to improve performance. An easy way is for scripts that are currently run concurrently and don't rely on each other to be run in parallel. My current batch file is as below

```
c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript1
start c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript2a
start c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript2b
start c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript2c
start c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript2d
c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript3
```

When run, it will run though the first, then start and run the 4 versions of 2 in parrallel but fail to run script 3. I'm wondering if there was a way to delay the running of script 3 until all version of script 2 have finished.

Comment: Don't use `start` if you want to _batch_ them.

Comment: Related: [How to wait all batch files to finish before exiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33584587)

Comment: @aschipfl, that is the link I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can run the second block and make it wait as described by @Aacini in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33586872/1417694).

```
c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript1
(
start c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript2a
start c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript2b
start c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript2c
start c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript2d
) | set /P "="
c:\pathtopython c:\pathtopythonscript3
```