# Redirected output file remains open after devenv.exe returns

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, visual-studio-2017

I have a .bat file with the following two commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\..\IDE\devenv" plugin\proj1-vs15.sln /rebuild "Release" /project plugin\proj1-vs15.vcxproj /projectconfig "Release|x64"  1>vcbuild.log 2>&1

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\..\IDE\devenv" plugin\proj2-vs15.sln /rebuild "Release" /project plugin\proj2-vs15.vcxproj /projectconfig "Release|x64"  1>vcbuild.log 2>&1
```

The first command completes successfully but the second one immediately fails with the message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

If I use a different filename for the redirected output in the second command then both commands complete without error.

I haven't had this problem with Visual Studio 2015 or any earlier versions, only with VS 2017.

Why is the redirected output file remaining open after the first devenv command has completed?

In my actual use-case having each execution of devenv.exe use a different filename for the redirected output would be inconvenient. Is there some way of ensuring that the output file is closed before the .bat file advances to the next command?

Answer (score 1):

Any child process that `devenv` spawns inherits the redirection handle, So if after debenv returns any of its child process is still open the file remains locked so CMD can not open `vcbuild.log` file the second time. The solution is to put both build commands in a redirected compound block.

```
(
    devenv <First Project Arguments>
    devenv <Second Project Arguments>
)>"vcbuild.log" 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know. Unfortunately it doesn't help in my case as the two invocations of devenv are in different batch files with some arbitrary set of commands executing in between them. That's why I need to ensure that devenv (and any of its child processes) is done with stdout and stderr before executing the next invocation of devenv.

Comment: I wonder why you didn't include that information in the first place. When devenv returns child processes are finished with stdout and stderr, inheriting a hanlde does not necessarily mean that a process can/will use it, otherwise you will have overlapping contents in console/RedirectedHanlde by a single devenv. some child processes may remain to complete their cleanup task or stay for while to listen to requests, so waiting for all child processes of devenv may result in your second build to start with an unexpected delay or never starts at all.

Comment: But I can't say anything about your batch files. I can list various methods to wait for all child instances of devenv but giving the answer to an obscure situation that may works for you by chance, have no value. Anyway there are already answered questions on SO showing how to wait for child processes, here is one of [them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33586872/4561332)