# Is there a way to run a batch of asynchronous commands a few at a time?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Suppose I want to run the following commands:

```
START foo.exe 1
START foo.exe 2
START foo.exe 3
```

and then when they complete I want to run

```
START foo.exe 4
START foo.exe 5
START foo.exe 6
```

How do I write a bat/cmd file to do it? I think the stumbling point for this is how do I tell when the previous batch of commands has finished so I can start a new batch of commands...

Comment: Do you plan on making sure all 3 previous commands completed, then start the new set?

Comment: See if the answers at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting) help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait all batch files to finish before exiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting). Alternatively, you could use a known `WindowTitle` for each and parse the output from `TaskList`, or check the `CommandLine` from 'Win32_Process' and proceed from there, e.g. `WMIC Process Where "Name='foo.exe' And CommandLine!='foo.exe 1' And CommandLine!='foo.exe 2' And CommandLine!='foo.exe 3'"…`.

Comment: Do you really want to run three copies of the same executable supplied with different parameters and when those have finished, another run with a separate set of parameters, or do you want to run the same executable against a pool of parameters but have only 3 executables running at any one time? Or are you anticipating switching the executables at some stage?