# pause and | usage in batch file(cmd)

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pipe, pause

I want to execute one command after the commands above were all done.

In fact, the kkkk.exe is simply delay 5s and rrrr.exe is delay 9s. I have tried the following codes and it works, but I dont know why.

```
 ::run.bat

    echo start test
    (

    start kkkk.exe

    start rrrr.exe

    )|pause

    echo ppp

    pause
```

What I know is:

- `|` : redirects the output of the first command to the input of the second command
- It seems that `|` will make sure the commands before `|` are done, so that it have output for `pause`. But simply run this code, the pause echo will show;

  > `press any keys to continue...`

  directly without waiting 9s(rrrr.exe). Why?
- After 9s, I don't need to actually input any key, the `echo ppp` will automatically be run, why?
- If I change `|` to `&`, I do need to input one key so that the `echo ppp` will be run, why?

Comment: Remove `start` (as this tells not to wait) or use `start /WAIT` (if you really insist in using `start`)...

Comment: @aschipfl: it works with a simple `start`, as long as none of the executables writes anything to the console. See also my comment above.

Comment: You forgot to include a [link to the original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting/33586872#33586872) where _two_ extensive explanations of the method are given: one in the answer itself and a second, more technical description by user eryksun, appears in the comments below...

Answer (score 2):

> `|` : redirects the output of the first command to the input of the
>   second command

correct.

> It seems that `|` will make sure the commands before `|` are done, so that
>   it have output for pause. But simply run this code, the pause echo
>   will show;
>
> `press any keys to continue...`
>
> directly without waiting 9s(rrrr.exe). Why?

Both sides of the pipe are executed as own processes. Of course `pause` will show it's prompt (that's the purpose of `pause`) and then wait for input (from the other side of the pipe which will give an "End of Stream" signal when finished, which is interpreted by `pause` as "ENTER"). If you want, you can suppress the message with `pause >nul`

> After 9s, I don't need to actually input any key, the echo ppp will
>   automatically be run, why?

included in explanation above.

> If I change | to &, I do need to input one key so that the echo ppp
>   will be run, why?

That's because `&` just means "and then do", so `pause` won't receive a signal from the previous commands and so waits for the keyboard.

**Note:** your results may be different when using other executables. Depending on how they are programmed, `start` (or even `start /wait`) may return immediately. (Especially with GUI applications).

Comment: _"Also if one of the executables writes anything to the console, `pause` will receive that ("Any key") and continue..."_ If the executable is started via `start` command, then a separate `cmd.exe` console window is opened for it, so there is no way that the `pause` command could receive any input form such an executable...

Comment: @Aacini: you're right. (wrong testing logic). Removed the wrong statement.

Comment: However, when i add code `cout<<"k1"<<endl;` in kkkk.exe and use call instead of start to run rrrr.exe and kkkk.exe, it seems that this should output k1 to the console and therefore, the pause will receive k1 and run `echo ppp` first instead of rrrr.exe. However, this is not right, it still run kkkk.exe(and k1 did not output to the console), rrrr.exe and then echo ppp. Why is that?

By the way, it seems that  `start call` is the same as just using `start`, am i right?

Comment: `start` starts a new independent process, so any output of a `start`ed application has no influence on the pipe; while  `call` executes the application within the same process. Therefore any output of a `call`ed application will be piped to the `pause`.

Comment: So only with `start` it's possible to run several apps at the same time. `call` will always wait until the app ends before continuing with the next command.