# How do i wait for the loop one to finish and then start loop 2

Tags: batch-file

```
::loop1
For /L %%A IN (1,1,15) DO (
start program1.exe  arg1 
)

::loop2
For /L %%A IN (1,1,15) DO (
start program2.exe  arg1 
)
```

I want to run loop2 only when all 15 instances or program1.exe from loop 1 have finished executing. I cannot use **call** since i want the programs to start in *parallel*.

Comment: [tasklist](https://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) should be helpful.

Comment: This can be done by surrounding the `FOR` command inside another paranthesized code block and piping it to the `SET /P` command.  Been a while since I have done it. I have to find the exact code. I did provide it as answer on SO in the past because I learned it from another user on SO. I think it was @Aacini.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait all batch files to finish before exiting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584587/how-to-wait-all-batch-files-to-finish-before-exiting)

Comment: I will test it soon, thanks. didnt know about the set /p trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%I in (1,1,15) do start "" program1.exe arg1

rem A real endless running loop is never a good designed loop.
rem For that reason use a second condition to exit the wait loop.
set "MaxSecondsToWait=60"

:WaitLoop
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 1 /NOBREAK >nul
%SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq program1.exe" /NH 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /C "program1.exe" >nul
if errorlevel 1 goto NextLoop
set /A MaxSecondsToWait-=1
if not %MaxSecondsToWait% == 0 goto WaitLoop
echo Timeout for all started program1.exe exceeded.

:NextLoop
for /L %%I in (1,1,15) do start "" program2.exe arg1
endlocal
```

`tasklist` always exits with `0` even on executable to find in list of running tasks cannot be found by `tasklist`. For that reason the filter output of `tasklist` is filtered by `find` which exits with `1` if the case-sensitive searched string is not found in output of `tasklist` which means there is no `program1.exe` running anymore.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `find /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `start /?`
- `tasklist /?`
- `timeout /?`

See also Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `>nul` and `|`.